# Sort django ListView based on calculated field in view

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

I want to sort the list from my model based on a (user-specific) field calculated in my views. I know how to order by the model fields using `class Meta`, but I have no idea how to do it if I want to use a calculated field in my views. In searching for the answer, the `extra()` method has come up, but django warns not to use it and that it will be deprecated in the future. Is there any other way to achieve this?

What I want to achieve: I have a `Song` model with `title`, `artist` and `lyrics` fields, and in my views I calculate how many words the user knows for every song, and this is the field I would like to order by. So the field is (extract):

```
for song in context['song_list']:
   stat = ((len(user_word)+len(set(already_known)))/(len(set(lyrics_list_))))*100
```

`Song` model:

```
class Song(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    url = models.URLField()
    lyrics_ru = models.TextField(max_length=1800)
    lyrics_gb = models.TextField(max_length=1800)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def lyrics_as_list(self):
        return self.lyrics_ru.split()
```

`Flashcard` model:

```
class Flashcard(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    deck = models.ForeignKey(Deck, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question = models.TextField()
    answer = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question
```

`KnownWord` model (this is if the user doesn't have a flashcard for the word, but he/she already knows the word, so it should also be considered a known word):

```
class KnownWord(models.Model):
    word_is_known = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    word = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="known_words", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    song = models.ForeignKey(Song, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.word
```

In the views I use the `lyrics_as_list` method to get a list of the lyrics. I also get a list of the user's flashcards. I do some other calculations (e.g. getting the dictionary form of the word) and then I can see how many of the words the user already has flashcards for, which is what I want to sort by.

Comment: You likely can annotate this. But I think in that case you should share the (relevant) models.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I've added the relevant models and some further details

Comment: It's a little confusing seeing the example you provide, since the variables within your excerpt don't utilize `song`
```
for song in context['song_list']:
   stat = ((len(user_word)+len(set(already_known)))/(len(set(lyrics_list_))))*100
```

That being said, you don't have to use the database to sort necessarily. If the number of objects is relatively small (< 1000 db entries lets say) you can use python's sort method in conjunction with your stat calculation.